# How to get the changed cells or added rows after Datagridview Sort

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have a DatagridView with datasource as follows:

```
bindingSource = DataTable
dataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource
```

When the cells are edited or new rows are added I apply a different formatting style, If I sort the dataGridView clicking on one of the column headers the formatting style is lost, So my question is:

After sorting the datagridview how do I know which cells changed or were added ?, so I can re-apply the formatting style

VB .Net or C# is OK

Comment: you can use another column(collapsed), with a boolean value, and then apply style for rows which new value is true, and nothing when false.

Comment: For the entire rows that seems to work but for specific cells?, the case is I need to know the specific cells, so I can Apply the style to only those cells not the entire row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally achieved the desired functionality adding a new field/column to the Datatable and instead keeping just one value for the entire row in that field, I store string representing the state/style for each cell like ",,E,,,E" so this sample string would indicate that the cell at index 2 and 5 should have an edited style.

I create/change that string in the CellValueChanged event, sample:

```vb
 Private Sub DataGridView_CellValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView.CellValueChanged
        If e.RowIndex = -1 Or IsNothing(DataGridView.CurrentCell) Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim cellPosition As Short = DataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
        Dim Styles(25) As String

        Dim stylesCell = DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("CellStyleDescriptor").Value

        If Not IsDBNull(stylesCell) And _
            Not IsNothing(stylesCell) Then
            Styles= Split(stylesCell, ",")
        End If

        If IsDBNull(DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Id").Value) Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To 25 'New row is being added
                Styles(i) = "N"
            Next
        Else
            Styles(cellPosition) = "E" 'Edited/Modified Cell
        End If

        DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("CellStyleDescriptor").Value = String.Join(",", String)
    End Sub
```

and read/apply the styles in the CellFormatting event, sample:

```vb
 Private Sub DataGridView_CellFormatting(sender As System.Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView.CellFormatting
        If e.RowIndex = -1 Or e.ColumnIndex = -1 Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim styles(25) As String
        styles = Split(DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("CellStyleDescriptor").Value, ",")

        Select Case styles(e.ColumnIndex)
            Case "E" 'Edited cell
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = modifiedStyle.BackColor
                e.CellStyle.ForeColor = modifiedStyle.ForeColor
            Case "N" 'New cell
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = newStyle.BackColor
                e.CellStyle.ForeColor = newStyle.ForeColor
        End Select
    End Sub
```

I hope this helps someone